# How to loop through a list of classes in Flutter dart and call a static method on each?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'd like to be able to do something like the following in order to avoid having to explicitly write out KlassOne.doSomething() then KlassTwo.doSomething(). The reason is that I will have many classes which will need to have this plus more duplicate logic and I don't want to keep repeating it. I understand that `dart:mirrors` is not in flutter so how do we accomplish this?

```
const List klasses = [KlassOne, KlassTwo];

class MyClass {
  void _aMethod() {
    for (final klass in klasses) {
      klass.doSomething(); // static method on both KlassOne and KlassTwo
    }
  }
}
```

Edit:

Running the above code results in the following runtime error:

```
NoSuchMethodError (NoSuchMethodError: Class '_Type' has no instance method 'getMissedEvents' with matching arguments.
```

Comment: You can't.  Instead of making `klasses` a `List<Type>` (in your code, it's actually `List<dynamic>`), you could do `List<void Function()> callbacks = [KlassOne.doSomething, KlassTwo.doSomething]` .  While it'd be more typing, it'd be more flexible (the functions could be named anything, and you can't really take advantage of them having the same name anyway).  Another possibility would be to explore code-generation.

Comment: Thank you @jamesdlin this is a good idea.